# How to build examples in CppKafka?

Tags: c++, cmake, cppkafka

I am investigating CppKafka library https://github.com/mfontanini/cppkafka

I want to build executables in `cppkafka/examples/`

My actions:

```
cd cppkafka/build
cmake ..
make -j
```

I was adding debug output in

```
# cppkafka/examples/CMakeLists.txt

message("XXXX123")
add_custom_target(examples)
macro(create_example example_name)
message("ZZZ")
```

I can see the output. But I don't see any executables in build directory. Where can I find binaries?

Comment: `cmake` only **configures** the project. For **build** the project, you need to run appropriate build tool after the configuration. E.g. if you have configured the project for "Unix Makefiles", then for build it you need to run `make`.

Comment: Of course, I was doing make, but I didn't find the binaries

Comment: Have you tried `make examples`? The call `add_custom_target(examples)` creates the target `examples`, but that target is not build during `make` or `make all`.